# Cannot debug internal page by netbeans and xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

My php.ini configuration:

```
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.106
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_log="D:\logs.log"
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.default_enable=on
```

Running XAMPP on windows 7,

So I can debug the site root http://mysite.local.com ,

But I can't debug internal page like http://mysite.local.com/admin !

Netbeans says: Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)

UPDATE:

My **breakpoint** is on a normal line on code

```
$a='foo';
```

UPDATE: **Found the solution**

It was related to the **Stop at First Fine** On the : Tools->Options->PHP->Debuging. This item should be checked to make breakpoints work.

**First I run the home page** and after that **I can debug internal pages by click links or enter url manualy**, It works well

Answer (score 0):

If I remember rightly, netbeans allows you to set breakpoints ***on lines that will not break!*** The following lines will not work: include(), require(), try{, catch() {, blank lines. This was pretty annoying for me.

Make sure that in your internal page php file, you're setting the break point on a function call or a variable assignment, then give it another go.

Apologies if this sounds obvious, it wasn't to me : )